# calculate average number in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a form with multiple textboxes. The user will use the amount of wanted textboxes. There is a limit of course. How do I use JavaScript to figure out how many of the textboxes contain data?

Example: if the user has entered numbers in three textboxes, I expect to get 3 as the result. Also, with this number, I want the average of the textboxes (that are not empty). So if three textboxes had values and they were 56, 78 and 78, I would expect (56 + 78 + 78) / 3.

```
Function send() {
val1 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_2.value);
if (isNaN(val1) == true ) val1=0;

val2 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_3.value);
if (isNaN(val2) == true ) val2=0;

val3 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_4.value);
if (isNaN(val3) == true ) val3=0;

val4 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_5.value);
if (isNaN(val4) == true ) val4=0;

val5 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_6.value);
if (isNaN(val5) == true ) val5=0;
document.form1.total.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5
}
```

i would like to divide by the number of textbox entered by the user
to get the average

Comment: parseFloat may prompt an exception if there is no value

Comment: Instead of adding up at the end, check that each value `!isNaN` and if  true, add it to a running total. At the same time, increment a counter of valid values. Then you just divide the running total by the counter at the end to get your average. For bonus points, put all your textboxes into an array so you can loop over it, or better yet use a class selector and loop over the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you'd need another counter with a loop which counts the occurences of NaN - else, an entered 0 will not be evaluated.

Once you have that, you can easily divide by that counter. So what you could do is this:

```
Function send() {
count = 0;
val1 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_2.value);
if (isNaN(val1) != true ) {
    count++;
} else {
    val1 = 0;
}
// repeat this for the other numbers as well

val2 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_3.value);
if (isNaN(val2) == true ) val2=0;

val3 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_4.value);
if (isNaN(val3) == true ) val3=0;

val4 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_5.value);
if (isNaN(val4) == true ) val4=0;

val5 = parseFloat(document.form1.valeur_6.value);
if (isNaN(val5) == true ) val5=0;
document.form1.total.value = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5) / count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to count how many valid values you have found.

You can simply use two variables:

- One with the sum of valid amounts entered in the fields
- Another one that you increment +1 when you find a valid amount in a field.

At the end you return the division sum/valid as average.

Beware of division by 0 in the case no field contains a value.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways to do it, but using plain Javascipt and keeping it (hopefully) easy to follow:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var total = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var num = parseFloat(values[i].value);
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            total += num;
            count++;
        }
    }
    var totalTb = document.getElementById("total");
    totalTb.value = count ? total / count : "NaN";
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input class="value" type="text"/>
    <input class="value" type="text"/>
    <input class="value" type="text"/>
    <input class="value" type="text"/>
    <input class="value" type="text"/>
    <br/><input type="text" id="total" readonly/>
    <input type="button" id="calc" value="calculate"/>
</form>
```

We attach a class to our input so we can select them with `getElementsByClassName`. Then we loop over that collection and try to parse the value in each one. If it is a valid number (i.e. `isNaN` return `false`), we add it to a running total and increment a counter of how many good values we've found. After the loop we just divide the total by the count (after checking count is greater than `0`).

Comment: it's cool but i would like to have only on textbox displayed, and after the user enter a value a second textbox come up automatically and so forth. Each time the user add more textbox the averare result pops up automatically in an another textbox